# What does the circumflex symbol mean in an expectation.

Tags: probability, expectation

I am working with Pareto Distributions with parameters $\alpha$ and $\theta$.

I have the equation $$E(X \wedge Y)=\frac\theta{\alpha - 1}\left[1-\left(\frac\theta{\theta+Y}\right)^{\alpha - 1}\right]$$

What does the wedge mean in this case?

Comment: It some time means "and", like $\cap$ (similarly, $\lor$ can mean "or", like $\cup$). But it's strange in this context.

Comment: It's hard to say without more context about what $X$ and $Y$ are.

Comment: It could mean $X\wedge Y = \min(X,Y)$

Comment: Hi Clark please make as an answer and I will mark correct.